# Question on Ricci flow and Einstein Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, ricci-flow

My knowledge on this topic is solely based on physics books, introductory texts on differential geometry and this one paper $[1]$.

One of the formulas of the paper shows what is called the *Ricci soliton equation:*

> $R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}_{X}g_{\mu\nu} - cg_{\mu\nu} = 0 \tag{1}$

In physics, a similar tensor field can be constructed: the *Einstein tensor*, given by:

> $R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = 0 \tag{2}$

**I would like to know: is it possible to have a situation where $\mathcal{L}_{X}g_{\mu\nu} =Rg_{\mu\nu}$, and $c=-\Lambda$ ?**

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2144

Answer (score 1):

A vector field $X$ is said to be a **conformal Killing vector field** if
${\cal L}_Xg=\varphi g$ some function $\varphi$. In special case $\varphi=0$ it is called a **Killing vector field**.

Consider an Einstein Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ of zero scalar curvature $R=0$ thus it is Ricci flat i.e. $Ric=R g=0$. If $(M,g)$ admit a Killing vector field $X$ (i.e. $\mathcal{L}_Xg=0$) then $(M, g, X)$ satisfies in your conditions. That is $0=\mathcal{L}_{X}g_{\mu\nu} =Rg_{\mu\nu}=0$ and $c=-\Lambda$ for zero Cosmological constant $\Lambda=0$.

For example $\Bbb R^n$ with Euclidean metric satisfies in your requirements. another example is torus $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1$ with flat metric because it admit Killing vector field.

All of these are correct if cosmological constant were zero, that I don't know what it is intuitively.